# NodeJS exec stop after some time without error

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, file, exec

I'm using `exec` from `child_process`.

The function runs fine but after 4-5minutes, it just stops, without any errors reported, but the script should run for at least 24hours...

Here is the code :

```
import { exec } from 'child_process';

function searchDirectory(dirPath) {
    let lineBuffer = '';

    const cmd = `find ${dirPath} -type f -name "*.txt" | pv -l -L 10 -q`;
    const findData = exec(cmd);

    findData.on('error', err => log.error(err));
    findData.stdout.on('data', data => {
        lineBuffer += data;
        let lines = lineBuffer.split('\n');
        for (var i = 0; i < lines.length - 1; i++) {
            let filepath = lines[i];

            processfile(filepath);
        }
        lineBuffer = lines[lines.length - 1];
    });
    findData.stdout.on('end', () => console.log('finished finding...'));
}
```

The `pv` command slows down the output, I need this since the path where I'm finding is over the network and pretty slow (60mb/s).

When I run the command directly in the terminal it works fine (I didn't wait 24hours but I let it for half hour and it was still running).

The processfile function actually makes an async call with `axios` to send some data to a server :

```
    let data = readFileSync(file);
    ...
    axios.post(API_URL, { obj: data }, { proxy: false })
        .then(res => {
            log.info('Successfully saved object : ' + res.data._id);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            log.error(err.response ? err.response.data : err);
        });
```

What could cause the script to stop? Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue, using `exec` is not recommended for huge outputs since it's using a limited size buffer. Use `spawn` instead :

> The most significant difference between child_process.spawn and
>   child_process.exec is in what they return - spawn returns a stream and
>   exec returns a buffer.
>
> child_process.spawn returns an object with stdout and stderr streams.
>   You can tap on the stdout stream to read data that the child process
>   sends back to Node. stdout being a stream has the "data", "end", and
>   other events that streams have. spawn is best used to when you want
>   the child process to return a large amount of data to Node - image
>   processing, reading binary data etc.
>
> child_process.exec returns the whole buffer output from the child
>   process. By default the buffer size is set at 200k. If the child
>   process returns anything more than that, you program will crash with
>   the error message "Error: maxBuffer exceeded". You can fix that
>   problem by setting a bigger buffer size in the exec options. But you
>   should not do it because exec is not meant for processes that return
>   HUGE buffers to Node. You should use spawn for that. So what do you
>   use exec for? Use it to run programs that return result statuses,
>   instead of data.

from : https://www.hacksparrow.com/difference-between-spawn-and-exec-of-node-js-child_process.html